# Specifying Log4j2 Configuration File When Using Executable JAR

Tags: java, logging, executable-jar, log4j2

I am having trouble specifying the Log4j2 config file location when using an executable JAR file. It works fine if I separate all the JARs, but when I try to combine them into one executable JAR file, for some reason the `log4j2.xml` file isn't picked up from the command line.

I've tried these two methods of specifying the location:

```
java -Djava.libary.path=..\bin -cp ..\config -jar MyApplication.jar

java -Djava.libary.path=..\bin -Dlog4j.configurationFile=..\config\log4j2.xml -jar MyApplication.jar
```

Neither of those are working. I've also tried adding the directory containing the config file to the classpath in the JAR's manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_21-b11 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.abc.MyApplication
Class-Path: ../config/
```

I haven't had success with this method either. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

---

EDIT

Ah, I believe I mistook the problem. Originally, this was the error I was seeing in the command line output:

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
```

But at some point while I was changing things, the error message changed without my realizing it to this:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

So what I figured out was that even though the executable JAR I was building was including the `log4j-core-2.1.jar` and `log4j-api-2.1.jar` JARs inside of it and in the `MANIFEST` file's classpath, there was a problem. The way I wrote my ant file to combine the libraries into the single JAR I was creating was successfully copying over the directories and class files, but was not copying over the other types for some reason, which are also obviously necessary (e.g. Log4j-config.xsd, Log4j-events.dtd, etc.).

To fix this, I changed the way I was merging the JARs in my Ant build file to this:

```
<jar destfile="${dist}/${jarName}" basedir="${classes}" 
    excludes=".svn">

    <!-- Merge this JAR with all the JARs in the lib directory, so that
    we are only creating one distribution JAR that includes all the
    libraries that you need. -->
    <fileset dir="${classes}" includes="**/*.class" />
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib}" includes="**/*.jar" />

    <!-- Specify the manifest file of the JAR -->
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.abc.MyApplication"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". ${manifest.classpath}"/>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

And that fixed the issue and copied over all files from the JARs into my newly created JAR.

Once this issue was resolved, the second of the commands I posted above worked for specifying the location of the configuration file. (As noted by `@rewolf` below, the first command won't work because the classpath specified in the `MANIFEST` of the JAR overrides any classpath specified on the command line.

Thanks for your responses, they definitely helped me get on the right path toward figuring out my mistakes.

Comment: So your config file is not inside the application jar?

Comment: No, I thought it was a better practice to keep the config file outside the JAR, so that the user could change the configurations if they desired. Do I need to include the file in the JAR?

Comment: How do you create your single jar? The log4j2-core jar contains config files that MUST be included or log4j2 will not work correctly.

Comment: Please add the output that you're receiving from log4j. I was assuming it is the default status logger complaining about no config file - but it might have been a mistake to assume so

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Something that isn't explained very well/obviously in the Java documentation is that if you're using an executable Jar, it will only use the Class-Path as specified in the Manifest file.  It will not listen to the `-cp` or `--classpath` arguments.

`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=directory/file.xml`

should definitely work though.  I'm assuming you're running on Windows given your slash direction.  Are you sure you are running it from the correct relative directory?

**Update**

I just tried it in Windows with no problems.  I used the following manifest:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: andrew.flower
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_67
Class-Path: lib/log4j-api-2.1.jar lib/log4j-core-2.1.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
Main-Class: com.andrew_flower.test.Log4jTest
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

The Log4j2 jars are located in a `lib/` directory and the `log4j2.xml` is in the `conf/` directory.  I executed the following command, and it found the config successfully.

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=conf\log4j2.xml -jar log4j2test1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Yes, I am running on Windows. I am 99.9% sure that I'm running it from the right directory. I've quadruple checked and I can't seem to see anything wrong with it.

Comment: works fine on  gitbash on windows

Answer (score 9):

For others who may have this issue...

1. Make sure your *-Dlog4j.configurationFile* options occur **before** your '-jar' not after.  Might seem obvious, but saw that mistake once.
2. Try treating the file location as a url and see if that works.  I.e. escape spaces with *%20* etc.  Also use 'file://*path*', replace backslashes with forwardslashes.
3. Windows paths can be written as *file://c:/path/to/log4j2.xml*

Hence if you have a log4j2.xml in your program folder for your exampleApp in `C:\Program Files\ExampleApp` then...

```
java.exe -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file://c:/program%20files/exampleapp/log4j2.xml -jar exampleApp.jar ...
```

...should work

Comment: works fine on gitbash on windows

Answer (score 9):

I solved the problem of specifying the location of log4j2 configuration in a runnable Jar that I created from Eclipse by including this in my java code:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "resources/log4j2.xml");
```

I have a package and so I needed to specify the path to my "resources" folder (in my "src" folder in Eclipse):

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "com/company/app/resources/log4j2.xml");
```

Notice I didn't include "src" in my path and I think it's the path in the "bin" folder that's required: ie in my case "com/company/app/resources/log4j2.xml"

My configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration> 

<appenders>

<Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n"/>  
</Console>

<RollingFile 
        name="RollingFile" 
        fileName="${sys:logFilename}"
        filePattern="${sys:logFilename}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log"> 
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level - %msg%n"/>      
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
  </Policies>  
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/> 
</RollingFile>

</appenders> 


<loggers>     
 <root level="all">
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>      
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/> 
 </root>    
</loggers>
```

Also notice I dynamically assign the rolling log file path + name "${sys:logFilename}" by including this in my java code:

```
System.setProperty("logFilename", "logs/myApp.log");
```

In order to get these 2 dynamic System.setProperty assignments to work they need to execute before the "getLogger" statement and so my java code looks like:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class MyTestLoggingClass {

 public static Logger logger = null;

 ...................
 setUpLogging();
 ...............

 public static void setUpLogging() {
    System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile",  "com/company/app/resources/log4j2.xml");
    System.setProperty("logFilename", "logs/myApp.log");

    logger = LogManager.getLogger(Logger.class.getName());  
 }
```

}

Having "logger" declared at the start of my class (but without invoking "getLogger" before my 2 System.setProperty statements) enables me to reference "logger" in other methods. I am obliged to initialise it though and so I chose "null" but then later update it with the "getLogger" statement - given this I can't make it "final" (can only assign it once) but can make it static - a constant class variable.

nb the 2 log4j2 jars I included in the build path are:

1. log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
2. log4j-core-2.6.2.jar

Comment: Best solution according to me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with version 2.8 of Log4j2.
This was gone when the respective Log4j2 jars were replaced with version 2.6 of Log4j2.