# How to reference external log4j2 configuration file using xi:include from external library?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

Tell me please, how to write path to file  inside the maven dependency with my custom configuration in `<xi:include href=""` in log4j2 configuration?

In my application I've added following maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>logging-libs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

this library contains file with custom configuration: `log4j2-include.xml`.

[image: My config library]

How can i write the path to my configuration file in `log4j2.xml` using log4j2 include feature.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logger.app" value="${spring:appName:-UNDEFINED}"/>
        <Property name="logger.appVersion" value="${spring:appVersion:-UNDEFINED}"/>
    </Properties>
    <xi:include href="log4j2-include.xml"/>
</configuration>
```

ERROR:

```
[Warning] log4j2.xml:7:44: Include operation failed, reverting to fallback. Resource error reading file as XML (href='log4j2-include.xml'). Reason: C:\Users\...\IdeaProjects\my-logging\target\classes\log4j2-include.xml (�� ������� ����� ��������� ����)
[Fatal Error] log4j2.xml:7:44: An include with href 'log4j2-include.xml'failed, and no fallback element was found.
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing C:\Users\...\IdeaProjects\my-logging\target\classes\log4j2.xml
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///C:/Users/.../IdeaProjects/my-logging/target/classes/log4j2.xml; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 44; An include with href 'log4j2-include.xml'failed, and no fallback element was found.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:261)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfiguration.<init>(XmlConfiguration.java:94)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.xml.XmlConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(XmlConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:533)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory$Factory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:457)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory.getConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:318)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:690)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:711)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:253)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogAdapter.java:155)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:122)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter.createLog(LogAdapter.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService.getInstance(LogFactoryService.java:46)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactoryService.getInstance(LogFactoryService.java:41)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:655)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:203)
    at my.pack.DemoLoggingApplication.main(DemoLoggingApplication.java:10)
ERROR StatusLogger No logging configuration
```

Answer (score 3):

The XInclude support in Log4j2 configuration was introduced in [LOG4J2-341](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-341).

The feature is very dependent on the underlying XML parser and has different limitations.

Among others, AFAIK, it does not allow to use a classpath resource for inclusion.

Please, consider read the James Hutton comment in the aforementioned issue:

> when using xinclude the path is interpreted as relative to the base
> directory, not the file including the additional configuration. Classpath
> protocol is not usuable either.

One thing you could try instead is combining the different configurations provided across the files in your library.

The process is described in the [Composite Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#CompositeConfiguration) section of the Log4j2 manual.

I never tested it, but it seems you can provide a comma separated list of configuration resources using the [configuration property](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) `log4j.configurationFile`.

Probably defining the `log4j.configurationFile` similar to the following could work in your use case:

```
log4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml,log4j2-include.xml
```

Please, consider read [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574905/specifying-log4j2-configuration-file-when-using-executable-jar).